# `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D array of shape (samples, 1000)). Found array with shape: (1, 5)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-2

A retrained the inception_v3 model for my own test data. (Backstory: im just trying to understand how the whole process works before im trying it on my 130 class "problem")

Now i got the .h5.
I tryed to import it and predict some image. But i only get the following error messages.

```python
ValueError: `decode_predictions` expects a batch of predictions (i.e. a 2D array of shape (samples, 1000)). Found array with shape: (1, 5)
```

May some can tell me what im doing horrible wrong?

my thoughts:
I read something that i need a vector of 1000 probabilitys (for 1000 classes) but i dont have them. 
How do i create such vector and set all 1000-my_num_of_classes(in my case 5) to like 0? 
I guess i have to preshape a 2d array of a size of 1000. But it dont get it what "samples" or in my case the "1" represent.
Or do i have to write some matching for my array of [1.0592173e-07 8.3998479e-09 9.9305904e-01 4.8276172e-05 6.8924953e-03] (in my case). Where i interprete that the 3 (id 2) class(which got trained) have the highest probability? 
So maybe like a file where i have all the trained classes in order like trained? to match the highest with the correspoding row (label)?

Would be awesome :)

That would be my code for predicition

```python
# Testing Inceptionv3
#from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import decode_predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image

my_model = load_model('my_model.h5')
#images = transform_img_fn([os.path.join('data','rose.jpg')])
img = Image.open('./data/rose.jpg')
img = img.resize((150,150))
img = np.array(img)
img = img / 255.0
img = img.reshape(1,150,150,3)

#base_model = inc_net.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

preds = my_model.predict(img)
for x in decode_predictions(preds)[0]:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `decode_predictions` utility converts the class predictions of a pretrained ImageNet model into the corresponding human-readable ImageNet classes.

Using "decode_predictions" only makes sense if your model outputs the ImageNet classes (1000-dimensional). Your model (`my_model`) appears to return predictions over 5 classes. It's not an ImageNet model.